# Double optional match in cypher query doesn't work as expected

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have pretty complex cypher query and this how it starts.

```
OPTIONAL MATCH (oldP:Profile {id: 3.0, type: "person"})
DETACH DELEte oldP
CREATE (p:Profile)
SET p.id = 3.0
SET p.type = "person"
```

I want to work it like when there is no Profile node with id:3.0 and type: person to just create this node but this node exists I want it to be deleted and then created again. This works as expected.

However, now I want to change this query to something like this.

```
OPTIONAL MATCH (:Profile {id: 3.0, type: "person"})-[:PROFILE_RELATED]->(toAttach)
OPTIONAL MATCH (oldP:Profile {id: 3.0, type: "person"})
DETACH DELEte oldP
CREATE (p:Profile)
SET p.id = 3.0
SET p.type = "person"
```

This I want to work exactly as the first one but before all of these I want to find all nodes with relation PROFILE_RELATED, and I want to store them in `toAttach` and send them down the query using WITH clause.

When I run this query when there is no node it works correctly. However when this node already exists I get "Node(344) already exists with label `Profile` and property `id` = 3.0" what I can do about it

Comment: Why delete and recreate instead of using [`MERGE`](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/merge/)?

Comment: Because during this query, I am not only changing this Node, but also some of its relationship and I assumed it was easier

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

1. Optional match for that profile and find the relationships
2. Delete the relationships
3. Create if not exists

```
OPTIONAL MATCH (oldP:Profile {id: 3.0, type: "person"})-[r:PROFILE_RELATED]->(toAttach)
DELETE r
MERGE (:Profile {id: 3.0, type: "person"})
```